# Headless content publishing, without the need for Component Templates

Tags: sites-9.1, sites-9.5

Does SDL Tridion 9.1 support this feature or its only supported in 9.5

**Headless content publishing** - publish components without the need for Component Templates.

Answer (score 3):

The concept of template-less, data-only publishing has been introduced in SDL Tridion Sites 9.5.

For more information, you can check this [link](https://docs.rws.com/816112/882559/sdl-tridion-sites-9-5-main-documentation/templateless--data-only-publishing).